# How to serialize a multidimensional array, a class member using boost?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

http://robot.kaist.ac.kr/haptics/chai3d-2.0.0_Doc/resources/html/structc_matrix3d.html

cMatrix3d has a class data member `double m [3][3];`

Now correct me if I am wrong : to serialise an instance of this class I need to just add this

```
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & m;//I think this is probably wrong, see error
    }
```

to class definition, right?

I get this runtime error : Unhandled exception at 0x758c9617 in client.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location 0x02209110

on the client side when I try to deserialise from a archive to an object instance.

```
std::istringstream iss(recvd_msg);
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss); 
            cMatrix3d rot;
            ia>>rot;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        {
            ar & m[i];
        }
    }
```